# Preserving (dynamically populated) dropdownlist items and selection inside of GView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I have a column in a GridView which has a Dropdownlist in the EditTemplate

The data for this dropdownlist is added dynamically (items.add()) after the user enters the edit mode for that row.

```
foreach (var bgElement in userCropList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Crop == cropToBeUpdated).BGs)
{
   ddl.Items.Add(bgElement.BG);
}
ddl.SelectedIndex = userCropList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Crop == cropToBeUpdated).BGs.FindIndex(d => d.Default == true);
```

When the user clicks the update button to save his changes, the page does a postback and as such lose the items aswell as the selectedindex which i need for the following bit in the RowUpdating event.

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GVCrops.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlAvailableBGs");
updatedCrop.BGs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.BG == ddl.SelectedValue).Default = true;
```

What came to my mind was to put the value the user selects in a viewstate variable and read from it in the RowUpdating event.

I am asking if there is an easier (not that it is hard) or already available thing that I am missing which could that for me?

**Edit:**

Ok, turns out my method ..

RowEditing():

```
ViewState.Add("SelectedBGIndex", ddl.SelectedValue);
```

RowUpdating():

```
if (ViewState["SelectedBGIndex"] != null)
{
   updatedCrop.BGs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.BG == ViewState["SelectedBGIndex"].ToString()).Default = true;
}
```

..is not going to work for the same reason apparently.
When the user clicks the update button for the row it will post back and the drop down list is reset with no selection and no items inside.

Seems like the solution would be a JavaScript function.
Any thoughts how to approach it?